# images and css not showing up in apache cordova

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I'm developing an android app using cordova. 
The index.html has the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Mobile</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/style.css">
    ...
```

My problems concerns the link tag. Although logcat output shows the embedhttp server serving up the style.css, the styles don't get applied to the html.

In contrast, the js files I include, seem to be working perfectly fine.

```
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  ...
```

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: I think href="style.css"

Comment: I tried that, as well as moving style.css to a css dir, renaming the path in index.html. The only thing that works so far is concatenating all the css files and including them in index.html, but that's a subpar workaround for something that works perfectly fine in a browser.</rant>

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem and I solved writing the path to the images relative to css file location and not relative to .HTML file location.

I have the following structure:

```
css
  index.css
images
  mage1.png
index.html
```

My css class, declared inside índex.css file, must be like this one:

```
body {
   background: url('../images/image1.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to be aware of is that cordova counts relative paths differently than your normal browser. So I would recommend not using relative paths for images but use the absolute path from the project "home". Ex:

```
body {
    background: url('images/image1.png');
}
```

This worked for me as I needed to keep a functioning version for a webapp as well as for a cordova nativified app.